# I want code of table in mysql without "Show columns" and "show create table"

Tags: mysql

I have a project where I must retrieve the data from a table, for example the column name, the size, if it is null or not, the problem is that I cannot use the following methods, and everything must be in a query, Can't use the console, does anyone know a solution?

I can't use this:

SHOW COLUMNS IN world.city;
SHOW CREATE TABLE world.city;

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database contains information about each table in the db -  see [information schema as show alternative](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/5.7/en/information-schema-introduction.html#information-schema-as-show-alternative), [information schema table reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-general-table-reference.html) from the MySQL docs.

You can `SELECT` the data you need directly from tables in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

For example:

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = <your_database_name>
```

should get you the names of all the tables in your database.

Answer (score 0):

In python :

```
#define `db` engine 
com_schema ="SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 
             'tbl_name';"
with db.connect() as conn:
    status = conn.execute(com_schema).fetchall()
```

Comment: Be careful that the table name should be inside the `' '`.